# How to add code mirror into sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, codemirror

When I put code mirror in one of the view, it keeps on saying that
"CodeMirror is not defined"

But I am sure that I have already installed code mirror into the project.

```
<%
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
    mode: {name: "javascript", globalVars: true}
  });
%>
```

Comment: And you include it using a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Yes it should be included by gruntfile by default